# this jQuery не работает

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, html5

Почему этот код работает:

```js
$("#i").click(() => 
{
    $("#i").css({"background-color" : "white"});
});
```

а этот нет:

```js
$("#i").click(() => 
{
    $(this).css({"background-color" : "white"});
});
```

Comment: Потому что стрелочная функция заменяет this

Comment: @andreymal спасибо

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME ответ выше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#i").click(function(){
    $(this).css({"background-color": "white"});
})
```

```css
#i{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="i"></div>
```

Comment: А где ответ на вопрос "почему"?